# Multi else if : if hasClass then do something

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Still pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery but considering the code below, how would you simplified it?

I mean, the first 2 conditions execute the same function except for a specific integer. The last else do not consider the `var sliderHeight`

Thanx for your help!

```
// Set the variable containing the slider height
var sliderHeight = jQuery(".royalSlider").height();
var contentHeight;
var contentTopPosition;

jQuery(".slide-content").each(function(){

if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("allCaps")){

    sliderHeight = sliderHeight + 20;

    contentHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);

    jQuery(this).css("top",-contentTopPosition);

} else if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("bigTitleAlignRight")){

    sliderHeight = sliderHeight - 6;

    contentHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);

    jQuery(this).css("top",-contentTopPosition);

} else {

    contentHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);

    jQuery(this).css("top",-contentTopPosition);
};                  
})
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited for this question.

Comment: Didn't know this one @Matthew. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it up in a `function` and use `$` for `jQuery`

```
var sliderHeight = $(".royalSlider").height();

$(".slide-content").each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent(".rsContent").hasClass("allCaps")){
        updateContent($this, sliderHeight + 20);
    } else if ($this.parent(".rsContent").hasClass("bigTitleAlignRight")){
        updateContent($this, sliderHeight - 6);
    } else {
        updateContent($this);
    }    
});
```

Then the `function`:

```
function updateContent($this, value){

    if(value != null)
       sliderHeight = value;

    var contentHeight = $this.height();
    var contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);

    $this.css("top", -contentTopPosition);
}
```

Comment: +1 for sensible refactoring with a function.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to steal the idea of refactoring with a function for my answer, but I'll +1 this instead of stealing your idea. ;)

Comment: Outstanding! I tweaked your solution because of a jQuery conflict we have here on the project but it works perfectly and it helps me to understand the best practices. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest change, preventing large amounts of repetition.  (Remember to keep your code DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.)

```
// Set the variable containing the slider height
var sliderHeight = jQuery(".royalSlider").height();
var contentHeight;
var contentTopPosition;

jQuery(".slide-content").each(function(){

if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("allCaps")){

    sliderHeight = sliderHeight + 20;

} else if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("bigTitleAlignRight")){

    sliderHeight = sliderHeight - 6;

}

contentHeight = jQuery(this).height();
contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);

jQuery(this).css("top",-contentTopPosition);
});
```

Go a step further, and replace your `jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent")` statements with a variable that you set once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sliderHeight = jQuery(".royalSlider").height();

jQuery(".slide-content").each(function(){
    var contentHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("allCaps")){
        sliderHeight = sliderHeight + 20;
    } else if (jQuery(this).parent(".rsContent").hasClass("bigTitleAlignRight")){
        sliderHeight = sliderHeight - 6;
    }
    jQuery(this).css("top", -(sliderHeight + contentHeight) / 2);
});
```

I removed some duplicate code. Other than that, I didn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick I think:

```
var $parent = jQuery(this).parent();

jQuery(".slide-content").each(function(){
  var sliderHeight = jQuery(".royalSlider").height(),
      contentHeight = jQuery(this).height(),
      contentTopPosition;

  if ($parent.hasClass("allCaps")){
      sliderHeight = sliderHeight + 20;
  } else if ($parent.hasClass("bigTitleAlignRight")){
      sliderHeight = sliderHeight - 6;
  }

  contentTopPosition = (sliderHeight/2)+(contentHeight/2);
  jQuery(this).css("top",-contentTopPosition);
})
```